# What counts as an ACOG Scope?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare

In season 6, the third Officer Challenge requires getting [40 longshot kills with an ACOG scope.](https://cod.tracker.gg/warzone/articles/modern-warfare-warzone-season-6-officer-challenges)

> Acog Longshots: Get 40 Longshot Kills while using an Acog Optic (6,000 XP)

I looked quickly through some ARs and I can't find any scopes that had the letters ACOG,
and searching it online brought me to [the wiki](https://callofduty.fandom.com/wiki/ACOG_Scope), but I couldn't find the information I was looking for.
The wiki has a list of CoD games the scope is in, but doesn't include the new Modern Warfare:

> The ACOG (Advanced Combat Optical Gunsight) is an attachment featured in Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare, Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2, Modern Warfare 2: Ghost, Call of Duty: Black Ops, Find Makarov: Operation Kingfish, Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3, Call of Duty: Black Ops: Declassified, Call of Duty: Black Ops II, Call of Duty Online, Call of Duty: Ghosts, Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare and Call of Duty: Modern Warfare Remastered.

Does anyone know which guns have an ACOG scope, or scopes that count toward this progression?
I like completing all these Officer Ribbon Challenges.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Answer:**

ACOG sights offer between a 3x and 4.5x zoom on a firearm, such as the "Scout Combat Optic" which offers 3.25x target magnification, or the "VLK 3.0x
Optic."
These would count towards this ribbon.

**Explanation:**

ACOG is a trademarked term and InfinityWard/Activision must have been unwilling or unable to purchase the rights to use the name in COD: MW (2019). Therefore it is necessary to identify what optical role an ACOG sight would fill.

ACOG sights are one of five potential optics types you could attach to a weapon. They stand among red dot sights, holographic sights, ACOG sights, sniper scopes, thermal scopes, and hybrid scopes. Generally:

- Iron sights refer to a weapon with no optic attached, and offer no enhanced magnification level when aiming
- Red dot sights provide a 1x-1.5x level of zoom when you aim down your weapon
- Holographic sights usually offer between 1.5x and 2.5x zoom level
- ACOG sights offer between a 3x and 4.5x zoom on a firearm
- Sniper scopes typically offer any level of magnification above 5x.
- Thermal sights usually exist above a 3x level of zoom, as well as allowing the user to see enemies through smoke.
- Hybrid sights allow the user to switch between an ACOG style of scope and a red dot style of scope but typically don't count towards iron sights, red dot, holographic, or ACOG challenges as they are a distinct type of optic already.

What this means is that you will be unable to identify an ACOG sight by name alone. Instead you will have to learn to recognize the optic's magnification capability to determine the type optic it actually is.

Comment: This is information from reality. Whether the game itself knows those scope are ACOG or not, and whether people can even test it to see if the achievement is tracked correctly... well, that's an entirely different story.

Comment: As somebody who plays COD: MW far, far, too often I can verify that the two optics I mentioned qualify for ACOG-based awards. Without a clear naming convention for ACOG scopes (unlike "Holo" optics or "Reflex" sights in-game) it is necessary to learn and identify what characteristics an ACOG scope has for identification

Comment: Oooh cool explanation, did not know ACOG was copyright, upvoted. I'm going to try out the Scout Combat Optic tonight and will accept this as the answer as soon as I get at least 1 longshot :)

Comment: No offense, but 95% of this answer could be cut down -- the answer could have boiled down to the last sentence since none of the other information is particularly relevant. Is it nice to know the historical context? Perhaps. Is it necessary to make a clear and concise answer? Yes.